# The Rule shared field in the item has been modified in the following templates during sitecore 8.1 upgrade to 9.1

Tags: upgrade

I am doing upgrade from 8.1 to 9.1 and get following collisions and warning

```
'C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\myinstance\Website\bin\System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll' file has been modified
```

How can i resolve this collision?

[image]

Comment: And what is your actual question?

Comment: please see the image above , the collision states that .. 
The 'Rule' shared field in the '/sitecore/templates/Branches/System/Path Analyzer/Site Map Group/$name/Assets' item has been modified.   how can i resolve this collision

Comment: Just let it overwrite. You shouldn't be changing system templates anyway. If you have good reason then update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should let the item be overwritten by the upgrade as

1. The item is for the Sitecore Path Analyzer to work.

   Normally, you should not be updating the default items of Sitecore with custom data since those are system based items.
2. You are moving from 8 to 9, so there have been lots of changes in terms of the Sitecore Analytics.